# How do I add more than one command to /etc/rc.local?

Tags: command-line, startup, bluetooth, brightness

I want to add two power saving commands to `/etc/rc.local` file.

This to disable Bluetooth:

```
 rfkill block bluetooth
```

And this to reduce screen brightness:

```
echo 3024 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Separately added to `/etc/rc.local` they work but not both of them together like this:

```
#/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 3024 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

rfkill block bluetooth

exit 0
```

How do I add the two commands to get them properly executed at start-up?

**Update**

It turned out to be a timing issue. I fixed it by delaying the execution of the first command thus:

```
(sleep 5; echo 3021 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)&
```

Comment: This should definitely work. My suspicion is, that the first command terminates with an error, although I cannot figure out why.  Since the Parameter -e is given in the very first line of the file, the shell script would terminate after the very first error without executing any more commands.

Comment: Tried again as above and it seems to be the brightness command that's the problem. Bluetooth is consistently killed on start up but the brightness is strangely only _sometimes_ reduced. Experimented with only the brightness command in the file with the result that, regardless of how I shut down, in less than 50% it works. Note that with both the commands in the file, as above, rfkill always works so the command doesn't terminate with an error, brightness just doesn't always take effect. Is there another place I could put 'echo 3024 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'?

Comment: yes, you could put in into the crontab for root. Run `sudo crontab -e` and insert a line `@REBOOT echo 3024 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. You have probably a timing problem in the form that the driver controlling display brightness is sometimes not yet loaded when the script comes up. You might or might not avoid this when using the crontab. The crontab can hold several lines, each user has its own crontab.

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried that I got 'no crontab for root - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.ytX5oW/crontab":22: bad time specifier
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)' - how do I save the changes properly?

Comment: whoops, my mistake, spell it `@reboot` ... small letters. Running `man 5 crontab` shows the documentation for this file format

Comment: Got the crontab installed but it doesn't work. Think you're right that it's a timing problem - seems like the brightness briefly flickers just before the login screen.

Comment: It's a dirty hack but why not do something like `(sleep 5; echo 3021 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)&`

Comment: A less hacky variant might use `udev` if that is available for your backlight. This would be best since it avoids the race condition entirely.

Comment: Do you mean adding `(sleep 5; echo 3021 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)&` to /etc/rc.local?

Comment: You should add a note to your question, or answer it below, for those that don't want to read the comments. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a timing issue. The OP indicated fixing it by delaying the execution of the first command thus:

```
(sleep 5; echo 3021 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)&
```

([Huckle](https://askubuntu.com/users/41418/huckle) had suggested this [in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208112/how-do-i-add-more-than-one-command-to-etc-rc-local/237913#comment260969_208112).)